# How is PHP instantiating this class?

Tags: php, zend-framework, software-design

I have a line of PHP that calls a new class as such:

```
$habits = new \Order\VO\Habits();
```

To me this looks like a static method call, but I can't tell what exactly is going on. I know that I have a class that follows that name space, and it is just a class that contains a bunch of variables. I can tell that this class is being instantiated, but I can't understand what the purpose for doing it in this manner is. I've never seen a class in PHP called this way, so any documentation as to what this actually is and why the class is being called in this way would be very helpful.

The project I'm in uses the Zend-Framework, so I'm not sure if this is something unique to the framework itself?

EDIT:

The way the class is being called is not a problem, I just want to understand more about what calling a class that was does, and WHY it would be better to call this specific class this way as opposed to simply using

```
$habits = new habits();
```

Comment: What makes it look like a static method call? Wouldn't that be Habits::static_method() ?

Comment: They're just using the fully qualified class name.

Comment: I'm just not familiar with this particular method of instantiating a class in PHP. why not simply do "new habits" like you would instantiate any other class? What is the benefit of using this, and how does PHP know what to do with that statement?

Comment: see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php - now my co-worker and I can both have a class called `Foo` as long as we keep them separated by our "own" namespaces.

Comment: So is it just the namespace being there that's the issue for you?

Comment: So this method is to be able to differentiate between classes of the same name within different name spaces? All thats happening here is they are explicitly telling PHP which class to load, as opposed to allowing PHP to try and determine what class to load automagically?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And it wouldn't surprise me if, for example, in something as big as Zend and related components, that there would be several classes with the same name, so it's as well to disambiguate them. This does exactly the same as `$habits = new Habits()` would if the new call and the Habits class shared a namespace.

Comment: Please make this an answer as it properly explains the concept to me. I'd like to award you for the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple complete example may help. Here I'm using the braced namespace syntax to scope the code into three namespaces in the one file, `\Order\VO`, `\Lifehacks`, and the global namespace.

```
<?php

namespace Order\VO {
    class Habits {
        function __construct() {
            echo "New VO Habits\n";
        }
    }

}

namespace Lifehacks {
    class Habits {
        function __construct() {
            echo "New Lifehack Habits\n";
        }
    }
}

namespace {
    // PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Habits' not found
    // $foo = new Habits();

    // Prints "New VO Habits"
    $foo = new \Order\VO\Habits();

    // Prints "New Lifehack Habits"
    $bar = new \Lifehacks\Habits();
}
```

Note that when in the global namespace, you can't just instantiate a Habits with `new Habits()`, as one doesn't exist in your namespace. You have to choose one or other of the `Habits` classes by prefixing them with a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate a class it's calling (at least 99% of the time in PHP 5) the `__construct()` function.

```
class Foo {
     public $bar;

     public function __construct($arg) {
         $this->bar = $arg;
     }
}
$class = new Foo('test');
echo $class->bar; // Ouput: test
```

In a namespace, your class lives inside what is basically a directory. Take `Foo`. I can't have two classes named the same thing, but I could put another `Foo` under a namespace.

```
namespace Example;
class Foo {
     public static function dump($arg) {
         echo $arg;
     }
}
```

So now we need to refer to which `Foo` we want. We can do this either by passing the full namespace

```
$class = new \Foo('test'); // The original Foo is in root namespace
\Example\Foo::dump('test');
```

Or by using `use`

```
use Example\Foo;
Foo::dump('test'); // alias here so we don't need to redeclare the path
```

Now, PHP doesn't "automagically" load classes. Instead, a common thing to do is to use an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) and then placefiles into a directory matching the namespace. So `\Example\Foo` would live in `example/foo.php` and your autoloader would simply include the file when you called the class.

Comment: That class that I'm instantiating in this case does not have a _construct method. Its simply full of variables, there are no methods at all. Its not the construction of the class I'm confused about, its why its being called the way it is that confuses me.

Comment: Added an explaination of namespacing

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are instantiating the class with the namespace, also you can do it this way:

```
<?php

use Order\VO\Habits;

$habits = new Habits();
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying for a more concise explanation. `$habits = new Habits();` won't work because the class name is `Order\VO\Habits`, not `Habits`. For convenience, you can import the namespace as in byoigres' answer, which tells PHP that the class `Habits` actually means `Order\VO\Habits`. After that, `$habits = new Habits();` will work.